# Custom Runtime Won't Use Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I have an App Engine service I deploy a custom runtime in a flexible environment. Deployments functioned normally on 11/20. On 11/21 `gcloud app deploy` stopped using the Dockerfile and began treating it as a non-custom runtime. Neither the app.yaml nor the Dockerfile have changed.

Below is a sample log from 11/20 and 11/21 respectively. You will note `Using Dockerfile found in...` of the first log is not present in the second log.

First log, 11/20:

```
2020-11-20 11:12:02,202 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app']
2020-11-20 11:12:02,547 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app', 'deploy']
2020-11-20 11:12:02,551 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--project: "distributed-computing-qa", --version: "9-2-0rc9"]
2020-11-20 11:12:02,621 INFO     oauth2client.client Refreshing access_token
2020-11-20 11:12:03,043 DEBUG    root            Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
2020-11-20 11:12:03,076 INFO     root            Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000021920ECA548>]
2020-11-20 11:12:03,526 DEBUG    root            API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
2020-11-20 11:12:04,419 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Services to deploy:

2020-11-20 11:12:04,420 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ descriptor:      [C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci\app.yaml]
source:          [C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci]
target project:  [distributed-computing-qa]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [9-2-0rc9]
target url:      [https://distributed-computing-qa.uc.r.appspot.com]

2020-11-20 11:12:05,272 DEBUG    root            No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
2020-11-20 11:12:05,274 DEBUG    root            Using bucket [gs://staging.distributed-computing-qa.appspot.com].
2020-11-20 11:12:05,941 DEBUG    root            Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [distributed-computing-qa]
2020-11-20 11:12:06,109 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Beginning deployment of service [default]...

2020-11-20 11:12:06,123 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [node_modules]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2020-11-20 11:12:09,085 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [server\node_modules]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2020-11-20 11:12:09,679 INFO     root            Using Dockerfile found in C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci
2020-11-20 11:12:09,679 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Building and pushing image for service [default]

2020-11-20 11:12:10,305 DEBUG    root            Could not call git with args ('config', '--get-regexp', 'remote\\.(.*)\\.url'): Command '['git', 'config', '--get-regexp', 'remote\\.(.*)\\.url']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2020-11-20 11:12:10,305 INFO     root            Could not generate [source-context.json]: Could not list remote URLs from source directory: C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci
2020-11-20 11:12:37,592 INFO     root            Uploading [C:\Users\BENJAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwbdhi28f\src.tgz] to [staging.distributed-computing-qa.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/distributed-computing-qa/appengine/default.9-2-0rc9:latest]
2020-11-20 11:13:03,413 DEBUG    root            Using builder image: [gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker]
```

Second log, 11/21:

```
2020-11-21 05:10:39,041 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app']
2020-11-21 05:10:39,177 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app', 'deploy']
2020-11-21 05:10:39,181 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--project: "distributed-computing-qa", --version: "9-2-0rc10"]
2020-11-21 05:10:39,203 DEBUG    root            Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
2020-11-21 05:10:39,231 INFO     root            Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x000001E60B3ED208>]
2020-11-21 05:10:39,522 DEBUG    root            API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
2020-11-21 05:10:40,196 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Services to deploy:

2020-11-21 05:10:40,198 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ descriptor:      [C:\Users\Benjamin 
Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci\app.yaml]
source:          [C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci]
target project:  [distributed-computing-qa]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [9-2-0rc10]
target url:      [https://distributed-computing-qa.uc.r.appspot.com]

2020-11-21 05:10:44,749 DEBUG    root            No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
2020-11-21 05:10:44,758 DEBUG    root            Using bucket [gs://staging.distributed-computing-qa.appspot.com].
2020-11-21 05:10:45,460 DEBUG    root            Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [distributed-computing-qa]
2020-11-21 05:10:45,645 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Beginning deployment of service [default]...

2020-11-21 05:10:45,658 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [node_modules]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2020-11-21 05:10:48,255 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [server\node_modules]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2020-11-21 05:10:57,261 DEBUG    root            Could not call git with args ('config', '--get-regexp', 'remote\\.(.*)\\.url'): Command '['git', 'config', '--get-regexp', 'remote\\.(.*)\\.url']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2020-11-21 05:10:57,261 INFO     root            Could not find any remote repositories associated with [C:\Users\Benjamin Filkins\Documents\Projects\Deployment\QA\dci]. Cloud diagnostic tools may not be able to display the correct source code for this deployment.
2020-11-21 05:11:19,099 DEBUG    root            Skipping upload of [.env]
2020-11-21 05:11:19,099 INFO     root            Incremental upload skipped 100.0% of data
```

There are four separate projects this is now occurring on. A co-worker can also confirm the same behavior. What I have tried and can confirm:

1. Updated Google Cloud SDK to latest version (319.0.0)
2. Confirmed Cloud Build API is active
3. Confirmed the Cloud Build service account has the App Engine Admin, Cloud Build Service Account and Service Account User roles
4. App.yaml and Dockerfile present in root and unchanged between attempts
5. App.yaml contains `runtime: custom` and `env: flex`

What I cannot confirm with certainty or prove did not have an impact:

1. Changes in OS (Windows 10), though no update had occurred during this time period
2. Changes in my GCP service account roles/permissions, though given the spread across four distinct projects and impacting multiple users seems incredibly unlikely

Any additional insight into this issue or additional items I may have missed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you raise a [support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs) in order that you receive further advice from the team

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by downgrading to SDK version 271.0.0. My machine has both Python 2.7 and 3 and I noted 274 and above began support for using Python 3.

Upgrading to 274 or above results in the reported issue. 273 and below (I only went as far as 267) does not have the reported issues. While I am currently unable to provide concrete evidence, my suspicion would be down to the SDK's ability to determine which version of Python to prefer. As noted [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#30000_2020-07-08) support of Python 2 was deprecated on 09/30/2020.